# Power BI, how do I show multiple selected values?

Tags: powerbi, dax, selectedvalue, slicers

So I have a graph where I have added 3 different measures. I also have a slicer with values "a", "b", "c" and "Select all". I would like to choose a letter on the slicer and have the graph show the right measure. Therefor measure 1 will show with the following condition: measure 1 = if(selectedvalue([slicer])=="a", expression measure 1) and the same for measure 2 and 3. This all works fine as long as I only choose one letter at the time. I would really really like to have multiple measures show simultaneously as to compare them but if I select multiple values in the slicer or if I select "select all" nothing will show in the graph.

I thought first that selectedvalue would just show a string with multiple concatenated values so I tried containsstring(selectedvalue([slicer]), "a") but I now understand that "selectedvalue" will go blank when multiple values are selected. Same goes for "values" and for "hasonevalue".

Does anyone know of a function that shows which MULTIPLE values are selected?

Please don't suggest taking away the condition and just having the graph show all the measures because in reality I have 10 and not 3 measures and it will become unreadable. Is there another way than splitting the slicer column up into 10 individual slicers? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a CSV:

```
CONCATENATEX ( VALUES ( 'Table'[Slicer] ) , [Slicer] , ",")
```